# Can't access the results of MS SQL stored procedure with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This area seems to be a "black hole" where I can't find any info on the web, any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a stored procedure that outputs a table. The problem is I can't access the results with my php code.

I called the stored procedure like this:

```
$table_init=mssql_init('joblisting_selector', $DBhandle) or die("Couldn't call stored procedure");
$table=mssql_execute($table_init, 'param');
```

This part doesn't return any errors but I have no way of accessing the table this procedure is supposed to return. if I do a var_dump($table) it returns as bool(false). If I try to use mssql_fetch_assoc($table) it returns null.

Does anyone know how to access a table that is created by a stored function?

Comment: did you select any database because if you do not select any database its not raise error

Answer (score 0):

mssql_execute returning false means it did not succesfully execute your statement/procedure.  if it returns false you should check out the result of mssql_get_last_message() which will give you specifics on your error.